# Difference between groovy-all-*.jar and groovy-all-*-indy.jar

Tags: groovy

What is actually the **difference** between these two files, `groovy-all-2.2.1.jar` and `groovy-all-2.2.1-indy.jar`, available in the `GROOVY_HOME\embeddable` directory?

I have not used the indy file so far and I am curious to know what it is used for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `indy` jar is a Java 7 compiled version of groovy with support for the new `InvokeDynamic` bytecode.

From the [Invoke Dynamic pages here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/InvokeDynamic+support):

> Since Groovy 2.0, we added support for the JVM invokedynamic
>   instruction. This instruction is supported since Java 7 and is a new
>   bytecode instruction in the JVM that allows easier implementation of
>   dynamic languages. This instruction will also be used internally, by
>   the JVM, for the upcoming lamdba support in Java 8.
>
> This means that unlike APIs, AST transformations or syntactic sugar,
>   this feature is not visible to the developer or the end user. It is a
>   compilation and runtime feature only

Comment: In the normal course of events for _new_ work then is th e "-indy"  JAR the recommended version?